# R - Produce a string that summarizes a vector of integers by replacing sequential values with the start and end value of the sequence

Tags: r

I am looking for an efficient way to simplify a vector of integers as a summary string, in order to format it to fit in a table cell.

For example:

```
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10)
```

should produce

```
"1-4, 6, 8-10"
```

This becomes especially useful in cases where printing all elements in the vector would quickly make the table unreadable.

e.g.

```
c(1:50, 53, 89:120)
```

should produce

```
"1-50, 53, 89-120"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to group the elements into blocks of consecutive integers.
`diff` can tell you if two consecutive elements are in the same block,
`cumsum` can number the blocks
and `tapply` can extract the first and last element of each block.

```
x <- c(1:50, 53, 89:120)
y <- tapply( x, c(0,cumsum(diff(x) != 1)), range )
# Format the result
y <- sapply(y, function(u) 
  if(u[1]==u[2]) u[1] 
  else paste(u,collapse=":")
)
paste(y, collapse=", ")
```

Comment: This is a very clean way of doing this that I have been trying to write for some time.  Thanks.  I would add that sorting first is probably adviseable `x <- sort(x)`